# A textbook question

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

[image]

This problem is from the book "A Basic Course in Real Analysis" by S.Kumerasan . I need help to solve this.

My ideas: Upon seeing this problem I plotted it on desmos but didnt get anything satisfactory. So I used this theorem which was in the same book given [image]

After this what is left here is to determine the continuity of such an f_1 that is as said in the theorem. But from here I cannot proceed.

So I need some help.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate LH derivative and RH derivative?

Comment: Using your theorem, set $c=0$. We obtain $f(x)=f(0)+xf_1(x)$. Is there a continuous $f_1$ that satisfies the equation?

Comment: The continuous function I found was x^n-1  when x>= 0 and x^m-1 when x<0. So now I have to show the continuity of f_1

Comment: Actually I want a rigourous proof of this thing

Comment: The only place you need to check continuity for is $x=0$. (The case is also different for $m$ or $n = 1$)

Comment: Thanks . I got it